# How to get values of an array in the alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sql-order-by, alphabetical

I have an array of strings plus one additional string. I want to use this string and values of array to get a set of string. Then I want to order the set of string alphabetically and extract the string which is the first in the list. What is the easiest way to do it in Java?

**ADDED:**

I wanted to do it this way:

```
List<String> playersList = Arrays.asList(players);
playersList.add(userName); // <---------- HERE IS A PROBLEM
Collections.sort(playersList);
```

I do not get any errors during the compilation. But during the execution I get a "UnsopportedOperationException". And it happens in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the minimum of an array of `String` with an additional external element, then you don't have to sort and extract first (which would be `O(N log N)`). You can do it in `O(N)`.

```
String minPlayer = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(players));
minPlayer = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(minPlayer, extraPlayer));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` wraps the array with an unmodifiable `List`, so when you try to add to it it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. What you could do it create a new a `ArrayList` and add your elements to it, then you're free to modify it afterwards.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(players));
list.add(userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either append the value to the array and sort it with Arrays.sort or create a List of the items and sort them using Collections.sort. The natural ordering of the strings will be alphabetical.

Comment: Do you know if Array.sort() generate a new array or it modifies the input array?

Comment: modifies the original but you could always pass a copy of it (or make a method that wraps Arrays.sort and makes a copy and returns that). Note is Arrays.sort not Array.sort

Comment: Thanks. I understood how to sort. But I cannot add a value to an array. First i tried `myArra[myArray.length] = newValue`. It did not work (index out of range). Now I am trying to use push. But compiler cannot find method push...

Comment: Right, there is no "push" method. Apache commons provides an easy way to do this http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html. Or you can just create a new array of your original size+1, copy the original array into it and then set the last element to the element you want to add.

Comment: I already started to use list. Now I have a list with all elements I need and now I try to sort it. I try to find out how to use `Collections.sort`.

Comment: I have managed to sort a list (I needed to import some stuff). Now i try to find out how to get a first element from a list.